# AngularJS + Ionic - Append content to another page/view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, append

I am new to angularjs and ionic and I can not seem to figure out how to append content to another page/view once I click a button. Right now once I click the "append" button the content appears below the button on the homepage but I want it to appear on the second page. Any suggestions?

**tab-home.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content>

    <h2>Welcome to Homepage</h2>
    <button class="button" ng-click="AppendText()">Append</button>
    <!--<div id="divID"></div>--> // Text 'Hi" only displays on homepage
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.AppendText = function() {
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     myEl.append('Hi<br/>');     
    }
})
```

**tab-second.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Second Page">
  <ion-content>

  <div id="divID"></div>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: View this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251243/how-to-add-html-code-dynamically-to-ion-content/34261287#34261287) it's added dynamic template page in HTML .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your trying to do things in a jQuery style way still. This needs a more Angular approach.

There are a couple ways you could handle this, but the right way is dependant on your app's functionality/layout/style etc.

**Option 1:**
If your using routing/states in your app, you can simply use an abstract route with a controller. Attaching your variable data in the abstract route's controller will cause nested routes to inherit that $scope.your.variable

**(app.js)**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('exampleState', {
    url: '/example',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/example/root-view.html',
    controller: 'ParentCtrl'
  })

  .state('stats.games', {
    url: '/games',
    views: {
      'stats-games':{
        templateUrl: 'templates/example/firstpage.html',
        controller: 'PageOneCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('stats.games', {
    url: '/games',
    views: {
      'stats-games':{
      templateUrl: 'templates/example/secondpage.html',
      controller: 'PageTwoCtrl'
    }
  })
});
```

**(controller.js)**

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.myValues = {
         value1:"some value",
         value2:"some other value"
   }
})
.controller('PageOneCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.message = $scope.myValues.value1
})
.controller('PageTwoCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.message = $scope.myValues.value2        
})
```

**(firstpage.html or seccondpage.html)**

```
<ion-view view-title="First/Second Page">
  <ion-content>

  <div id="mainMessage">{{message}}</div>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Option 2:** You could make a custom directive like this and substitute the data to your needs. This example shows two ways to mod your DOM.

```
    .directive("mydirective", function(){
        return {
            template: "<h1>Hi, ...</h1>", // or use an html file here
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false, //default
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){ 
                console.log([scope],[element],[attrs]);
                console.log(scope.myValues.value1);
                /// use element from here
                // do something...
                // element.append("hello <br>")
            }
        }
    });
```

and then in your .html file you include

```
<div mydirective> </div>
```

**Option 3:** This is **my favorite way to share content/data between views**... Services or Factories in AngularJS are amazing. Create a service, and inject it into and module controller for instant shared access to data from several controllers:

```
.service("myDataService", function() {
    var myData = {
        dataSetOne: {
            name: "John Doe",
            message: "hi, John",
            other: "misc info"
        },{
        dataSetTwo: {
            name: "John Doe",
            message: "hi, John",
            other: "misc info"        
        }
    }
})
```

then in your controller just make sure you include the service and a dependency injection:

```
.controller('yourPageCtrl', function($scope, myDataService) {
    $scope.myData = myDataService;
    $scope.message = "Hi "+$scope.myData.dataSetOne.name;
    // do something here 
});
```

and your DOM would look like this:

```
<div id"someID">{{message}} </div>
```

Last and worst option, if all else fails, is to use $rootScope. I really don't recommend that approach and thus am going to leave that to you to research if needed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Let me know if you run into troubles. #3 really is worth the learning curve (which isn't that big), as you will inevitably use it more as you use Ionic more. I'm on skype to if you need more hands on help (colemanjeff)

Comment: Quick question Jeffrey with this third option can you one use strings/text to share and access data across different pages? For example if I want to use a column?

Comment: By far the best explanation, I had no idea about services. Thank you! BTW, whats the difference between .factory and .service?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your app module with the two state pages that you want:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
  })
  .state('music', {
    url: '/music',
    templateUrl: 'music.html'
  });
});
```

Then on app start, $stateProvider will look at the url, see if it matches the index state,
and then try to load home.html into the .

Pages are loaded by the URLs given. One simple way to create templates in Angular is to put
them directly into your HTML file and use the  syntax.
So here is one way to put home.html into our app:

```
<script id="home" type="text/ng-template">
  <!-- The title of the ion-view will be shown on the navbar -->
  <ion-view view-title="Home">
    <ion-content ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
      <!-- The content of the page -->
      <a href="#/music">Go to music page!</a>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</script>
```

This is good to do because the template will be cached for very fast loading, instead of
having to fetch them from the network.

Comment: Yeah I've seen this in the docs before. How does this help with what I am trying to accomplish above?